# Tensorflow keras, no gradients error when use MSE

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying the code from tensorflow "[Writing a training loop from scratch](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch)" with some changes by myself. I changed the loss function from SparseCategoricalCrossentropy to MeanSquaredError. I also changed the architecture of the model by adding a new Lambda layer for loss calculation. However, I have the Value error that no gradients provided for variable. Is there any way that I can make the code to run with MSE?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,), name="digits")
x1 = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(inputs)
x2 = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(x1)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, name="predictions")(x2)
final_outputs = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.argmax(x, axis = -1))(outputs)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=final_outputs)

# Instantiate an optimizer.
optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)
# Instantiate a loss function.
loss_fn = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

# Prepare the training dataset.
batch_size = 64
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1, 784))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (-1, 784))

# Reserve 10,000 samples for validation.
x_val = x_train[-10000:]
y_val = y_train[-10000:]
x_train = x_train[:-10000]
y_train = y_train[:-10000]

# Prepare the training dataset.
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(batch_size)

# Prepare the validation dataset.
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, y_val))
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(batch_size)


epochs = 2
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))

    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            logits = model(x_batch_train, training=True)

            loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)

        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)

        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

Answer (score 0):

`argmax` ops is [not differentiable](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/math_grad.py#L38). To use an integer label and MSE loss, you want to convert your labels `y_train` and `y_val` to integers.

```
y_train = np.argmax(y_train, axis=-1)
y_val = np.argmax(y_val, axis=-1)
```

And adjust the output layer to output integer labels

```
outputs = layers.Dense(1, name="predictions")(x2)
```

Comment: Hi, I just figured it out that the number of output units could be the problem. Do you think it is suitable to one hot encode the output space? like 0 will be a vector with length 10 with the first value to be 1 and all others to be 0. After I make this change, I can successfully run the code but now the loss is not the actual MSE I expected.

Comment: I think you first need to clearly define in your question what the MSE you're looking for is like. To answer your question, if you one-hot encode the output and compute MSE for *all* labels, you are actually computing [Brier score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score). 

If the MSE you want is between a predicted probability and actual probability for a *single* label, then you can one-hot encode the prediction and use an additional *input mask* to mask all the element at other labels of your prediction.